# Connecting new BizTalk node to cluster fails with EntSSO

Tags: biztalk, msdtc, biztalk-2013

I've been tasked with setting up a new, third, node in our BizTalk 2013 R2 cluster. The server is up and connected to the windows cluster. BizTalk is installed and patched to CU8, the same patch level as the other nodes.

When I try to configure the BizTalk installation everything works fine with the Enterprise SSO part, However as soon as I try joining the BizTalk installation to the group I get the error:

> You have specified to join a BizTalk group that is pointing to a
>   different Enterprise Single Sign-On (SSO)  Master Secret Server.  You
>   will need to re-configure the local Enterprise Single Sign-On to join
>   to the  same SSO system.

I've tried the following:

- Changed the SSO database with ssomanage to point to the exact location as the other, secondary, node we have.
- Delete the BizTalk config and started from scratch
- Change the MSDTC settings to correspond with the ones seen on the secondary node
- Restarted the server

I've tried googling the issue but can't find anything, everything LOOKS like it's in order, but obviously not. If I look in the Event Log I find this:

```
The SSO service is starting.
Computer Name: Server3
SQL Server Name: DbCluster1
SSO Database Name: SSODB
Not using SSL. See documentation for details on how to secure the SQL Server connection.
```

Followed by:

```
Got the current secret from the master secret server.
Secret Server Name: DbCluster1MSDTC
MSID: 8b3af315-d9e6-46b0-a5d4-ab354d43644c
```

And followed by:

```
Got the previous secret from the master secret server.
Secret Server Name: DbCluster1MSDTC
MSID: 8b3af315-d9e6-46b0-a5d4-ab354d43644c
```

Which seems, to me, like EntSSO gets all data needed. However after this I find this in the EventLog:

```
The run-time environment was unable to initialize for transactions required to 
support transactional components. Make sure that MS-DTC is running. 
(DtcGetTransactionManagerEx(): hr = 0x8004d01c)
```

Not sure if this is connected in any way, but I do know that I'm all but out of ideas on how to solve this. Google is usually my friend, not today though.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unconfigure anything on the new server.

Run BizTalk Setup again and *remove* the Enterprise Single Sign-On Master Secret Server option under Additional Software.

That's actually the Master Secret Server which you already have.  The SSO client comes with the BizTalk Runtime option.

Then reconfigure the new server joining the new server to SSO and Group.

Comment: I tried uninstalling all BizTalk related components and BizTalk itself and re-install BizTalk (no adapter pack, no HIS and no CU:s at first) and configure it again and run into the exact same problem. I can't however find any other EntSSO server running in the network so it's a bit of a mystery what it is actually trying to connect to.

Comment: @JaggenSWE It's Additional Software / Enterprise Single Sign On Master Secret Server.  Join should be the only option on SSO tab when you run Configuration.